# oraclesql - Search for missing salesimport data

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a two tables (one with data about 'salesimports' and next with a data about shops).

This is an example data:

```
shop    city    importid    importtype  importtime  committime  endtime
S410    KURSK   1107597374  PSCN    2016-06-17  2016-06-17  2016-06-17
S004    KIEV    1107595750  PSCN    2016-06-17  2016-06-17  2016-06-17
S230    WARSAW  1107595594  PSCN    2016-06-17  2016-06-17  2016-06-17
S115    LVIV    1107595507  PSCN    2016-06-17  2016-06-17  2016-06-17
S220    PRAGUE  1107595458  PSCN    2016-06-17  2016-06-17  2016-06-17
S179    MINSK   1107595328  PSCN    2016-06-17  2016-06-17  2016-06-17
S247    HOMEL   1107595264  PSCN    2016-06-17  2016-06-17  2016-06-17
S202    ROSTOV  1107595114  PSCN    2016-06-17  2016-06-17  2016-06-17
S132    BERLIN  1107595112  PSCN    2016-06-17  2016-06-17  2016-06-17
```

The select I use to take data from both tables:

```
select f.shid shop, f.ctid city, i.limportref importid, i.simporttype importtype, 
       centrala_user.borlanddatetostr(i.itp) importtime, 
       centrala_user.borlanddatetostr(i.gtp) committtime, 
       centrala_user.borlanddatetostr(i.edp) endtime
from oracla.imports i 
join oracla.firm f on i.shid = f.shid
where f.byact = 0 
and f.bytype = 0
and i.simporttype not in ('PSXN')
order by i.itp desc;
```

My plan is to get a select, that gives me an info about shops that had no imports during last days, or whole 'salesdata' from a shop is missing in the salesimports table.

I tried few solutions with 'and not in' and 'and not exists' but it didn't give me a result I wanted.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not show, what you have tried. Did you try something like this:

```
select f.*, 
      (select max(centrala_user.borlanddatetostr(i.itp)) from oracla.imports i where i.simporttype not in ('PSXN') and i.shid=f.shid) as last_import_date
  from oracla.firm f 
 where f.byact = 0 
   and f.bytype = 0
   and f.shid not in  (
      select distinct i.shid
        from oracla.imports i
       where i.simporttype not in ('PSXN')
         and centrala_user.borlanddatetostr(i.itp) > trunc(add_months(sysdate,-1))
   )
```

Because is not clear, what LAST DAYS means, I have used one week ( trunc(sysdate -7 ) )

Comment: Thank you, this is what I almost wanted.

Sad to say, but I used the similiar way, however I searched f.shid not in firm f instead of imports... Dont ask me why. Probably were preetty much tired and went out of coffee.

The last thing is that I will have to figure out how to show the last importdate

Comment: Ok, it gives me a list of shop that had no any single imports.

But now I have hot to figure out how to view the shops that have also missing imports during last 'month' and show the date of last import into main server.

Comment: @headder If under the Last Month is one month back, you can use add_months(sysdate,-1). For the last date use inline select. I have changed the SQL.